# Navigating away from a page with angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an angularapp inside a regular Rails 4 app, so the angular app only works in a specific controller/action and does not work in other places, i have setup everything correctly but once i enter the route of the angular app the browser's back button always sends me back to the angular app route, i want the back button to navigate away from this section as it would do with any other section, is this possible? here is my routing setup...

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
                  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
   
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl: ROOT_URL + 'api/partial/take_course',
      controller:'ClassController'
    })
    .when('/section/:section_id', {
      templateUrl: function(params){
        return ROOT_URL + 'api/section/' + params.section_id;
      },
      controller:'ClassController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```